# Improve GeoServer WMS tile loading delay

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, generate-tiles

I'm using OpenLayers 2.13 and GeoServer 2.3.5 for my development.
Following code is I'm using for loading map tiles..

```
map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
    "LoadedLayers",
    url,
    {
        width: '1062',
        height: '286',
        srs: 'EPSG:3857',
        layers: multipleLayers,
        styles: '',
        format: 'image/png',
        bgcolor: '0x80BDE3'
     },
     {
        singleTile: true,
        //tiled: true,
        //tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom,
        ratio: 1,
        visibility: true,
        isBaseLayer: true
    }
);
```

While using `SingleTile:true` option map is taking around 10 to 15 seconds to load the tiles.Here only single wms request is going to server.

Then I have tried to use like below

```
tiled: true,
tilesOrigin : map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom,
```

But, here also its taking around 10 seconds to load map complete tiles.And the `width:` and `height:` of the tile is changed to 256. And here around 20 to 24 request is going to server.

Can we change the width and height in `tiled:true` option.? or is there any other method to improve wms tile loading delay using limited wms request.

Sample Single Tile GeoServer request url:

```
localhost:7080/geoserver/wms?LAYERS=layer%3Alanduse_district_border%2Clayer%3Alanduse_city_border%2Clayer%3Alanduse_builtup_area%2Clayer%3Alanduse_park%2Clayer%3Alanduse_lake%2Clayer%3Arailway_line%2Clayer%3Apoi_railway_station%2Clayer%3Aroad_colony%2Clayer%3Aroad_minor%2Clayer%3Aroad_major%2Clayer%3Alocation_placename%2Clayer%3Alocation_major_placename%2Clayer%3Alocation_major_cityname%2Clayer%3Apoi_bus_stand%2Clayer%3Apoi_hotel_restaurant%2Clayer%3Apoi_hospital%2Clayer%3Apoi_airport%2Clayer%3Apoi_police_station&WIDTH=1062&HEIGHT=286&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&BGCOLOR=0x80BDE3&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=77.123507022705,28.607589532471,77.305811405029,28.656684686279
```

Sample Single Tile GeoServer request url:

```
localhost:7080/geoserver/wms?LAYERS=layer%3Alanduse_district_border%2Clayer%3Alanduse_city_border%2Clayer%3Alanduse_builtup_area%2Clayer%3Alanduse_park%2Clayer%3Alanduse_lake%2Clayer%3Arailway_line%2Clayer%3Apoi_railway_station%2Clayer%3Aroad_colony%2Clayer%3Aroad_minor%2Clayer%3Aroad_major%2Clayer%3Alocation_placename%2Clayer%3Alocation_major_placename%2Clayer%3Alocation_major_cityname%2Clayer%3Apoi_bus_stand%2Clayer%3Apoi_hotel_restaurant%2Clayer%3Apoi_hospital%2Clayer%3Apoi_airport%2Clayer%3Apoi_police_station&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&BGCOLOR=0x80BDE3&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=77.16796875,28.65234375,77.2119140625,28.6962890625
```

Comment: What is the performance when you are using the preview functionality in Geoserver? Since you are using so many layers, GeoServer itself might be taking so much time to render the images. Can you use cached services?

Comment: Hi, Devdatta Tengshe..Thank you for the response.. I'm Getting GeoServer preview in 3 to 4 seconds. But, I can't load these multiple layers in cached format. Layer data will be change daily so that i have to use only WMS format..

Comment: You are requesting for multiple images from 18 different layers; Of course it will take some time.